# HTML Search element styling

Tags: html, css

I´m trying to build a search element together with a button, something like:

Except that I need to change the background color of the search icon (blue, gray, whatever...).

Here is my code so far and the result:

```css
.searchWrap {
  position: absolute;
  border: thin solid #f2f2f2;
  border-radius: 5px;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
}

.searchTerm {
  float: left;
  border-style: none;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 20px;
  outline: none;
}

.searchButton {
  right: -50px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ccc;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div className="searchWrap">
  <input type="text" className="searchTerm" placeholder="Search..." />
  <button type="submit" className="searchButton">
          <Icon name='search' />
       </button>
</div>
```

I'm using React. Here is my result so far:

[image]

The external border is rounded, ok, that's what I need, but the separation between the searchTerm and the searchButton is also rounded, and I need a plain separator here, something like:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using font awesome here, so the code isn't spaced like your screenshot, but looks like you have your own library you're using with react for that icon and your spacing is fine.

All you need to do is use `border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0` to keep the left side borders from rounding, and assign a `border-left` on the `.searchButton` to draw the vertical line. I changed the border color so it's more prominent, but you can use whatever color you want.

```css
*{margin:0;padding:0;}
.searchWrap {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
}

.searchTerm {
  float: left;
  border-style: none;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 20px;
  outline: none;
  margin-left: 3px;
  border: thin solid #ddd;
  border-width: thin 0 thin thin;
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
}

.searchButton {
  right: -50px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 32px;
  border: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ccc;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: thin solid #ddd;
}

.searchTerm:focus, .searchTerm:focus + .searchButton {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="searchWrap">
    <input type="text" class="searchTerm" placeholder="Search..." />
    <button type="submit" class="searchButton">
      <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
   </button>
 </div>
```

Comment: @ChrisHappy are you referring to the input spacing and how the submit doesn't fill the input height?

Comment: @ChrisHappy did you read my description? I could have just not given a solution with a working code snippet... but assumed it's fine sine that spacing isn't OP's problem. They have the elements in order, they just need the CSS I mentioned in the post.

Comment: True, I'm just a little of a perfectionist... Added `height: 30px`.

Comment: Talking about perfectionism, my OCD just kicked in - I'd recommend a `margin-left: 3px` for `.searchTerm` to prevent the left-hand radii from getting clipped.

Comment: @Conan lol I should have just left the snippet out of the answer and posted the CSS :) OP's got the wrapper, input, button, and icon in place. They just need to nix the top-left/bottom-left border radius and add a left border to the button. But went ahead and added that. I'm trying not to make it too confusing for OP, either. I tried to keep just the changes they need in the CSS I applied.

Comment: Great job! Thanks !

Comment: One more thing, what if I need to change border color when user click on input to type somehing (control focus).  I´m trying to set the searchTerm border but looks so strange. Any hint here ?

Comment: @Mendes what's "control"?

Comment: Focus. Corrected.

Comment: @Mendes updated my answer - like that? if not, describe exactly what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Yes, yes, yes. Thanks a lot @Michael Coker. Very helpfull.

Answer (score 1):

Try this for the search button css instead of `border-radius`

```
.searchButton {
    ...
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    ...
}
```

Comment: You got the border, but they also said... *"and I need a plain separator here"*

Comment: @MichaelCoker ah didn't notice that bit of the question

Answer (score 0):

Can you use bootstrap? Relatively simple, and once you have it, modify the css the way you want it.

https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/input-group/#button-addons

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This question **asks** for the answer to be provided in React. Please try to avoid writing answers that ask for clarification, as they don't immediately solve the problem at hand. Once you have 50 reputation, you will be able to [**add a comment**](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment) to a question in order to ask for clarification. Until you have 50 reputation, please try to provide answers that [**don't require clarification**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead) from the asker :)

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap is strongly recommended for this. See http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups.  Coupled with FontAwesome, you could do something like this:

```
<div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for...">
  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">
      <span class="fa fa-search"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Search</span>
    </button>
  </span>
</div>
```